# Removing vertical dotted lines in Dev-C++

Tags: ide, dev-c++

Hello how do I remove the vertical dotted lines in Dev-C++? I tried unchecking all the boxes in the text editor options, still no luck! :(

[image]

Comment: These lines are there for your protection of screwing-up indentations, like when you wear belts in cars preventing concussions or other major injury when you are in a car-crash.

Comment: Yes I get your point, but I'm used to not having it like the older version of the ide. It kind of ticks me off when I format and arrange my code because so much vertical lines gets added.

Comment: I guessed it was either your comment or newbie in action. I have that with tabs in another editor. That's why I pushed for "Looks OK" during triage review. Maybe posting a Dev C++ settings picture from preferences as well?